# Add subsection in ToC with memoir

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, memoir

With memoir, it seems like that only chapter/section is shown in ToC, but I need to show subsection in ToC with memoir document. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\title{Document}
\author{prosseek}
% }

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{The Domain Problem and Stakeholders}
\section{First}
abcdef.
\subsection{Sub}
def

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\title{Document}
\author{prosseek}
% }
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}        %% added
\settocdepth{subsection}           %% added
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{The Domain Problem and Stakeholders}
\section{First}
abcdef.
\subsection{Sub}
def

\end{document}
```

[image]